# ListView is not updating

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have an ItemCart. I would like to show the CartItems in a listview, with ItemName and quantity.
When I press a button, the quantity of the item in listView should increase.

My problem:
The CartItem of the observableCollection is increased each time i pressed the button correctly, but the UI is not updating/refreshing. Is anyone there who can help me??

Here is the code:

```cs
public class AboutViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public AboutViewModel()
    {
        AddCartItem = new Command(AddItem);
    
        cartItems = new ObservableCollection<CartItem>();
        cartItems.Add(new CartItem { ItemName = "Item1", Quantity = 4 });
        cartItems.Add(new CartItem { ItemName = "Item2", Quantity = 2 });
    }

    public ICommand AddCartItem { get; }
    
    public ObservableCollection<CartItem> cartItems;
    public ObservableCollection<CartItem> CartItems
    {
        get { return cartItems; }
        set
        {
            cartItems = value;
                    
            OnPropertyChanged("CartItems");
        }
    }

    void AddItem()
    {
        cartItems[0].Quantity++;
        CartItems = cartItems;
    }
}
```

```xml
<StackLayout>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CartItems">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding ItemName, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Detail="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
<StackLayout>
                
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
        <BoxView
            Color="Blue" />
        <Button Text="Add Name" Command="{Binding AddCartItem}"/>
```

Comment: is `AddItem` supposed to add a **new** item to the list, or increase the quantity of an **existing** item?  If it is supposed to increase the quantity, how do you know which item to increase?

Comment: You're updating the value of the first entry in the `cartItems` backing field of type `ObservableCollection` (which should ideally be `private` BTW) and then you're updating the reference of the public `CartItems` property for some reason, which isn't necessary. Your UI will only update in this case, if any of the items inside the collection actually invokes a `PropertyChanged` event. Can you show where and how the `CartItem` class is defined?

Comment: Use a CollectionView instead, it has better performance and it's susceptible to changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to refresh UI once changing the value of property `Quantity` in model `CartItem` , you need to implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `CartItem`.

Based on your code, I have achieved this function, you can refer to the following code:

**CartItem.cs**

```
public class CartItem: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }

        //public int Quantity { get; set; }
        int _quantity;
        public int Quantity
        {
            get => _quantity;
            set => SetProperty(ref _quantity, value);
        }

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

**AboutViewModel.cs**

```
public class AboutViewModel 
    {
        public AboutViewModel()
        {
            AddCartItem = new Command(AddItem);

            CartItems = new ObservableCollection<CartItem>();
            CartItems.Add(new CartItem { ItemName = "Item1", Quantity = 4 });
            CartItems.Add(new CartItem { ItemName = "Item2", Quantity = 2 });
        }
        public ICommand AddCartItem { get; }

        public ObservableCollection<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }

        void AddItem()
        {
            CartItems[0].Quantity++;
        }
    }
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:listviewapp="clr-namespace:ListViewApp"
             x:Class="ListViewApp.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <listviewapp:AboutViewModel></listviewapp:AboutViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CartItems}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding ItemName, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              Detail="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Button Text="Add Name" Command="{Binding AddCartItem}"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**Note:**

1.In fact, you don't have to define another variable `cartItems` at all.
You can only define variable `CartItems`:

```
public ObservableCollection<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
```

2.For document [ObservableCollection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-7.0), we know that this class:

> Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when
> items get added or removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

So, if you add modifiers `public ObservableCollection<CartItem>` for variable `CartItems`,when you add or remove one or more Items to this list, the UI will be updated. And if you want the UI refresh automatically after you change the value of property `Quantity` in model `CartItem` , you need to implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `CartItem`.

```
public ObservableCollection<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
```